# Meu input checkbox não acompanha o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

O que eu quero fazer com o `checkbox`, é o mesmo que o `radio` faz usando o *JavaScript*.

Porque eu então simplesmente não uso o `radio`?

É porque se o `radio` aparecer marcado, não tem como eu deixá-lo desmarcado.

Sei que a lógica no *JavaScript* está certa, porque dá para ver pelo `console.log`, mas quando eu clico em outro `input` ele não desmarca o que está marcado.

```js
var obj2 = "";
var box = document.querySelectorAll(".t");

box[0].addEventListener("click",selecionarGru);
box[1].addEventListener("click",selecionarGru);

function selecionarGru(){

  if(obj2 == "" || obj2 == this){
      if(obj2 == this){
        obj2.removeAttribute('checked');
        obj2 = "";
        return;
      }
      obj2 = this;
      obj2.setAttribute("checked","");
   }else{
      obj2.removeAttribute('checked');
      obj2 = this;
      obj2.setAttribute("checked","");
   }
}
```

```css
#tudo1{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.t{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
</div>
```

Comment: nao poderia criar mais um radio com opção nenhum?

Comment: Sim, seria mais facil tinha pensado nisso antes do seu comentario e ja to fazendo assim! porem esta dando merda do mesmo jeito. 

minha ideia usar o js para verificar se eu dei um segundo clique no mesmo radio sendo assim ele iria marcar um radio invisivel. porem eu coloco o atributo checked no radio invisivel e ele nao desmarca o visivel

https://codepen.io/pedroviskks/pen/YYNBog

Comment: adiciona uma id em cada checkbox que voce deseja e faz o ciclo usando o checkbox e não o nome do campo pq voce não consegue puxar pelo this o outros elementos ao mesmo tempo só um deles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outra alternativa é a cada vez que clica num elemento desmarca todos os outros. Para isso pode utilizar [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para remover apenas o elemento que tem, e de seguida aplica `checked = false` nos que sobraram:

Exemplo:

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".t");
boxes.forEach(boxClick => boxClick.addEventListener("click",function(){
  [...boxes].filter(box => box != this).forEach(box => box.checked = false);
}));
```

```css
#tudo1{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.t{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
</div>
```

Note que o [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) devolve um [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que não tem o método `filter`. Por esse motivo utilizei o [*spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) que são os `...` em :

```
[...boxes]
```

De forma a criar um array normal e poder utilizar `filter`, que filtrou retirando apenas a caixa que está a ser clicada:

```
filter(box => box != this)
```

E após retirada a caixa clicada apliquei `checked = false` aos restantes com:

```
forEach(box => box.checked = false)
```

Com esta solução pode ter quantas `checkboxes` quiser que irá funcionar como pretende, deixando sempre no máximo uma selecionada.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `previousElementSibling` e `nextElementSibling` para saber qual `checkbox` está clicando.

Ao clicar no primeiro `checkbox`, o `previousElementSibling` será **null**, logo fica fácil saber se o `checkbox` clicado foi o segundo, aí basta desmarcar o outro.

**Veja:**

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll(".t");

box[0].addEventListener("click",selecionarGru);
box[1].addEventListener("click",selecionarGru);

function selecionarGru(){

   var obj1 = this.previousElementSibling,
       obj2 = this.nextElementSibling;

   (obj1 || obj2).checked = false;

}
```

```css
#tudo1{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.t{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tudo1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
  <input type="checkbox" class="t">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
<script> 
var elements  = document.querySelectorAll('.t');
elements.forEach(function(value, key){
    elements[key].addEventListener("click",selecionar);
});

function selecionar(item)
{
    let marked = this.checked;

    elements.forEach(function(value, key){
    elements[key].checked = false;
  });

  if(marked === true) this.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

E teste aqui: 
https://jsfiddle.net/sLpevgae/32/

Comment: Mas do jeito que vc fez depois que vc da o Check no botão não da para tirar mais! Justamente o que ele NÃO quer...

Comment: Muito bem observado, corrigido. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Um código simples pra fazer isso

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="item1"><input type="checkbox" name="selecionar" id="item1" data-info="item1" value="item1"> Item 1 </label><br>
    <label for="item2"><input type="checkbox" name="selecionar" id="item2" data-info="item2" value="item2"> Item 2 </label><br>
    <label for="item3"><input type="checkbox" name="selecionar" id="item3" data-info="item3" value="item3"> Item 3 </label>
</div>

<script>
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-group input[name=selecionar]');
    inputs.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].getAttribute('data-info') !== e.target.value) {
                    inputs[i].checked = false
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```